# Where is JSON type post request data located?

Tags: javascript, php, http, xmlhttprequest

When I use `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to make a POST request using JavaScript

```
var url = "http://localhost:80/response.php";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") // Setting content-type

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
        document.getElementById('div_response').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
};

var data = "message=Hello";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.send(data);
```

POST request data in **response.php** is located in `$_POST` variable when `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
if(isset($_POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['message'])) {
    echo $_POST['message'];
}
```

But, when I change the Content-Type to  `Content-Type: application/json`. Where is my posted JSON data located in PHP. Because `$_POST` doesn't contain any data when `Content-Type: application/json`.

Comment: It's in `php://input`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved